# error: expression is not assignable (to part of C pointer)

Tags: c, c-strings, memcpy, strcpy, strlen

I am getting this error:

```
error: expression is not assignable
                                *fullmsg+(fmsglen+10) = output;
```

for trying to assign a string pointer to a part of another string pointer. Why is this happening and how can I fix this? Here is the full code:

```
int main(){

    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons(4583);
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(server));
    char* fullmsg = (char *) malloc(10010);

    char* command = (char *) malloc(75);
    int commandlen;
    char* output = (char *) malloc (5000);
    int fmsglen = 0;
    while (1){
        recv(sock, command, 75, 0);
        commandlen = strlen(command);
        if (*command == 'c' && *command+1 == 'd'){
            command[commandlen-1] = '\0';
            int stat = chdir(command+3);
            if (stat != 0){
                output = strerror(errno);
                send(sock, output, 5000, 0);
            } else {
                send(sock, 0, 0, 0);
            }
        } else{
            FILE * cmd = popen(command, "r");
            while (fgets(output, 5000, cmd) != NULL){
                *fullmsg+(fmsglen+10) = output;
                fmsglen = strlen(fullmsg);
            }
            sprintf(&fullmsg, "%10lu", strlen(fullmsg));
            send(sock, fullmsg, 10010, 0);
            pclose(cmd);
        }
    }
    free(output);
    free(command);
    free(fullmsg);
    return 0;
}
```

All help is appreciated (I know this is probably a mistake with an easy fix but I'm relatively new to C)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this statement

```
*fullmsg+(fmsglen+10) = output;
```

in the left hand side of the assignment there is used a value of the type int. You may not assign one value to anothr value. Moreover in the right hand side there is an object of the type char *. So in any case this assignment does not make sense.

Even if you will rewrite the statement like

```
fullmsg+(fmsglen+10) = output;
```

nevertheless again in the left hand side there will be a value that may not be assignable.

It seems you mean something like the following

```
strcpy( fullmsg + fmsglen + 10, output );
```

That is you want to copy the string pointed to by the pointer `output` to the character array pointed to by the pointer `fullmsg` with the given offset `fmsglen + 10`.

Also it seems that instead of this if statement

```
if (*command == 'c' && *command+1 == 'd'){
```

you mean this statement

```
if (*command == 'c' && *( command + 1 ) == 'd'){
```

And this loop even if you will use the standard C function strcpy to copy string

```
while (fgets(output, 5000, cmd) != NULL){
    strcpy( fullmsg + fmsglen + 10, output );
    fmsglen = strlen(fullmsg);
}
```

is not correct because you can add 10 several times to the length of the result string.

And this statement

```
sprintf(&fullmsg, "%10lu", strlen(fullmsg));
```

should be rewritten at least like

```
sprintf( fullmsg, "%10zu", strlen( fullmsg ) );
```

But this is also wrong because the call places at the beginning of `fullmsg` a string (zero-terminated) that represents the value of the expression `strlen( fullmsg )`. You need a separate string of the size 11 bytes that will be used in the call of `sprintf` to convert the value to string and then you can use the function `memcpy` to copy this string in the beginning of the string pointed to by `fullmsg`.

Comment: Saying that _the left hand side there will be a value that may not be assignable_ is not applicable to in the manner of pointers.

Comment: @snr I do not know what is the "manner of pointers". I pointed out that the both statements with a pointer expression or without a pointer expression are wrong.

Comment: hmm, that's my lack sorry likewise your english.